# Making forms that have double columns

Tags: html, css, forms

So i have this form that i quickly made and i got it so that i can make double columns now.

link: http://codepen.io/zomdar/pen/WbXBaq

```
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>

            <form>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="zip">Zip / Postal code</label>
                    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                    <select id="country" name="country"><option></option></select>
                </div>
                <div class="full">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="copy" name="copy">
                    <label for="copy">Send me a copy</label>
                </div>
                <div class="half right">
                    <input type="submit" value="send">
                </div>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset { width: 900px; }
input[type=text], select, textarea { width: 98%; }
.half { float: left; width: 48%; padding: 1%; }
.full { clear: both; width: 98%; padding: 1%; }
.right { text-align: right; }
```

but the problem is that when i put the div tag half and put it in the html....i have to put 2 "half" fields for it to go to the next line. I cant just put 1 half class and another half class right below the half class. Any ideas on how i can do that? add another class maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a class `.clear { clear: both; }` like this:

```css
fieldset { width: 500px; padding: 1%; }
input[type=text], select, textarea { width: 98%; }
.half { float: left; width: 48%; padding: 1%; }
.clear { clear: both; }
.full { clear: both; width: 98%; padding: 1%; }
.right { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact form</legend>
            <form>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div><!-- added div class clear -->
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="zip">Zip / Postal code</label>
                    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                    <select id="country" name="country"><option></option></select>
                </div>
                <div class="full">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="copy" name="copy">
                    <label for="copy">Send me a copy</label>
                </div>
                <div class="half right">
                    <input type="submit" value="send">
                </div>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```